# GET method not supported when trying request method as delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Below is my method to delete and return a string, simple and straightforward

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deletetest", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public String DeleteUser() {
    return "something";
}
```

But I go Get method not supported, which is weird since i state that my method = RequestMethod.DELETE

Comment: This is the expected behavior if you set DELETE as request method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set an endpoint to RequestMethod.DELETE the endpoint will only accept a HTTP DELETE request. Your browser issues a GET request. So you can use request method as get or you can use postman to issue a delete request.